# Flutter app drops java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError (couldn't find "libflutter.so")

Tags: android, flutter

I've built an app written on Flutter and it's running well on my device.

On client device however it is crashing at start (even before Centry initiates).

When connected To ADB we got this log:

```
 AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.travel.exchange-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.travel.exchange-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.travel.exchange-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"

 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary (Runtime.java:367)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary (System.java:1076)
  at io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.startInitialization (FlutterMain.java:172)
  at io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.startInitialization (FlutterMain.java:149)
  at io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication.onCreate (FlutterApplication.java:22)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1037)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6496)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800 (ActivityThread.java:229)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1887)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7406)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I'm building specifically using arm64 (app crashes even on my device if I'm trying to run on arm (32).

```
flutter build apk --release --target-platform=android-arm64
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add following code under the **buildTypes** in **android\app\build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

When building your application in release mode, Flutter apps can be compiled for armeabi-v7a (ARM 32-bit), arm64-v8a (ARM 64-bit), and x86-64 (x86 64-bit). Flutter does not currently support building for x86 Android (See [Issue 9253](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253)).

Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Comment: Now it by default supports these 3. Source: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#build-an-app-bundle

Answer (score 9):

in app level build.gradle following line should be added

```
    defaultConfig {

        ...

    ndk { abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a","x86_64", "mips", 
         "mips64", "arm64-v8a" }

}
```

Comment: This one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case, someone out there may find this useful, if like me they stumble on this thread while almost losing their minds for 2 days!

Background: I upgraded to [AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility) and was trying to integrate Braze's flutter plugin which is dependent on firebase.

What finally worked: I removed the following dependencies from the app/build.gradle

> implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1"
>
> implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1"

And added the following dependencies to pubspec.yaml

> firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
>
> firebase_messaging: ^5.1.2

I suspect there is something in there that makes it fail, not sure, but this worked for me in resolving this issue. If you encounter a similar issue, it maybe be helpful to check your dependencies on Android's build.gradle and flutter's pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 1):

This was an interesting error. It took me a whole day to get around it. I tried adding the `ndk.abiFilters` as per the answers on here but this alone didn't solve my problem (at least not for my case). I tried building the app in release mode using `flutter build apk --release` and it built the apk without any problem. That is when I realized that the issue might be from the emulator itself (I was using a Pixel 2 API 30). So I tried running the app on a real device (Samsung M30) and it ran without any problem. I then became sure that this was definitely from my emulator (besides to the build.gradle config listed on here). The issue was solved when upgraded my emulator to Pixel 4XL API 33 (x64).
Just incase you need it, I have also arranged the ndk.abiFilters as mentioned on here (since I want the app to be built on both x86 and x64 arm models). I setup mine as follow:

```
...
defaultConfig{
      ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have get this problem now and after searching, trying many time I resolved it I note here to hope can help anyone hit case like me.

My case:

- I build my apk in release mode on my phone Xiaomi and it working good. I go to the folder and copy that file to another old android device and get this bug.

Resolved:

- Because flutter will fix so file for special device I connected (Xiaomi) so it will remove some so file no need and that apk file size about 85MB.
- I run `build apk --release` with no connected device and it generate new apk file about 95MB. this apk can run all mode I need.

Comment: So need to run $ build apk universal ?

Comment: you can run `build apk --release` with no connected device. the universal build I just try again and it not work let I edit my post

Answer (score 0):

In my case error was at play market testing, and adding: `android:exported="true"` in AndroidManifest, helped

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

This is because Flutter used to make an APK compatible with either 32-bit or 64-bit but not both.

However, the issue is resolved by Flutter team recently. Upgarde/Switch to flutter master channel (if you aren't using it). Now, a single command `flutter build apk` will produce the apk compatible with both 32-bit and 64-bit architecture. To switch to master channel use command `flutter channel master`. And `flutter upgrade` to upgrade the flutter sdk.

Comment: Which flutter version fixes the problem? Can you reference the GitHub issue?

Comment: The post is 6+ months old. I don’t remember the version number. I must have upgraded the SDK 4-5 times and never observed this issue after Jun 2019.

Comment: I still have the issue on v1.12.13+hotfix.9 and wanted to make sure it's not due to running an old version.

Comment: It looks like this issue is still open per> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37566

Answer (score -4):

Solution is described in this article. 
https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-app-couldnt-find-libflutter-so-c95ad81cbccd

TL;DR;

In build.gradle of app this lines should be added:

```
android {
     ...
    defaultConfig {
       ....    
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
```

Build should be made using `flutter build apk`

Comment: This config only work when run `flutter build apk`, do not work when run `flutter run`

Comment: if I add this, I can no longer run my app in Android Studio. It says "Installing APK..." and freezes.

Comment: This solution doesn't work because it will force the generation of a 32-bit only build as described in the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.
Based on Google Play's documentation "Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need to support 64-bit architectures.". You can read more about it at https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit
For a solution read more at: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29710#issuecomment-643247365

Comment: This is outdated. The play store no longer accepts 32 bit.