# Flutter Issue: Native crash

Tags: flutter

After deploying my Flutter app on Google Play it crashes on startup. It was working for 2 devices (Google Test Devices on Play) and for other devices it was giving following errors.

> Issue: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/abc.pota.tallxy-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/abc.pota.tallxy-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/abc.pota.tallxy-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"

So I put the following code in my app/build.gradle file.

```
defaultConfig {
    ..
    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
}
```

But not on all the Google Test devices and even my mobile (when I download it from Google Play) it crashes with following error.

**Issue: Native crash of abc.pota.tallxy**

> ---
>
> 04-09 18:33:39.560: E/HwSystemManager(1901): HandleInstalledPackageInfoService:second action: pkgData is null
>   04-09 18:33:39.683: E/HwLauncher(2408): PowerSaveLauncherModel onPackageAdded:  not inPowerSaveLauncher 
>   04-09 18:33:39.908: E/fm_if.c(16065): find the id:fm and begins to open the devices
>   04-09 18:33:39.939: E/Finsky(6061): [135] com.google.android.finsky.setup.ae.a(52): Error when prefetching preloads
>   04-09 18:33:39.939: E/Finsky(6061): com.google.android.finsky.setup.fetchers.RawDocumentsFetchException[reason=pai_config, account=[3IPbcy9bVZDdTfTescMyODo8-OY]]
>   04-09 18:33:39.939: E/Finsky(6061):     at com.google.android.finsky.setup.ae.a(SourceFile:31)
>   04-09 18:33:39.939: E/Finsky(6061):     at com.google.android.finsky.setup.ag.call(Unknown Source)
>   04-09 18:33:39.939: E/Finsky(6061):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   04-09 18:33:39.939: E/Finsky(6061):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>   04-09 18:33:39.939: E/Finsky(6061):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>   04-09 18:33:39.939: E/Finsky(6061):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)
>   04-09 18:33:40.174: W/System(16106): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/YouTube/lib/arm64

**Exception After removing all the proguard code. Google console says it failed for the below four devices.**

> Device(s) with issues
>   Google Pixel 2 (walleye) - Android 8.1
>   Huawei Mate 9 (HWMHA) - Android 7.0
>   Google Pixel (sailfish) - Android 7.1
>   Samsung Galaxy S9 (US) (starqlteue) - Android 8.0
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/abc.pota.tallxy-xsLCE7j_6PxDsQ0AqFF1ZA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/abc.pota.tallxy-xsLCE7j_6PxDsQ0AqFF1ZA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/abc.pota.tallxy-xsLCE7j_6PxDsQ0AqFF1ZA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/abc.pota.tallxy-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/abc.pota.tallxy-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/abc.pota.tallxy-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64,

My **app/build.gradle** is as below.

```
        def localProperties = new Properties()
        def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
        if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
                localProperties.load(reader)
            }
        }

        def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
        if (flutterRoot == null) {
            throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
        }

        def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
        if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
            flutterVersionCode = '1'
        }

        def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
        if (flutterVersionName == null) {
            flutterVersionName = '1.0'
        }

        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

        def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
        def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
        if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
            keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
        }

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 28

            lintOptions {
                disable 'InvalidPackage'
            }

            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "abc.pota.tallxy"
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 28
                multiDexEnabled true
                versionCode 5
                versionName flutterVersionName
                testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
                ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
            }

            signingConfigs {
                release {
                    keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                    keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                    storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                    storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
                }
            }

            buildTypes {
                release {
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.release

                }
            }
        }

        flutter {
            source '../..'
        }

        dependencies {
            testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
            androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
            implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
            implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        }

        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have not tried yet. Will try today and update the post

Comment: I removed all the code related to minify and proguard. Generated new apk and deployed but getting same error.

Comment: Do you get this error in your device too (in release mode)?

Comment: When I connect my device to the computer and run it then no... But if I download the it from Play Store (Internal Release) then it crashes

Comment: When you build the release version `app-releases.apk` and install it in your phone (before publishing it on the Play Store), does it crash?

Comment: I directly install from the Android Studio by clicking on the Run button and it will install the app on my device. This app doesn't crash. But I have not tried installing app-release.apk by putting it on phone and then install... I will try it today. Thanks foryou time @CopsOnRoad

Comment: I tried installing the app-release.apk on my device but it is not working too :-(
 I have added the exception from my developer console in my question

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle (app)`?

Comment: Yes, I have posted the gradle file.

Comment: Files look OK to me but why do you need `ndk.abiFilters` and change `signingConfigs.release` to `signingConfigs.debug`.

Comment: As I was getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError error I put teh ndk.abiFilters according to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795414/flutter-app-drops-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-libflutter-so) post. Also as I am planning to release my app then also I need to keep signingConfigs.debug?

Comment: Yes, you can keep the debug, I have also done that in my app and it works fine. You can try that.

Comment: I tried with debug but it still fails on my local too.. I also tried removing the ndk filters but no luck... it becomes very frustrating... :-( Thanks for your time @CopsOnRoad

Comment: I think a better solution that you can get is by filling an issue [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md)

Comment: Yes, I have opened an issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31162
Thanks for your time and help @CopsOnRoad

Answer (score 0):

This is a flutter version issue, Try deploying with flutter 3.1.0 and dart version 2.18.0.

**As a temporary hack**, you can set minSdkVersion to 29 it prevents Play Store from checking against the Pixel 2 (API 28) and allows “reviewing” to complete. Unfortunately, this will prevent your app from working on any device earlier than Android 10.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `minifyEnabled true` you will have to face this issue.

---

**Solution 1**

Remove this line in your `build.gradle` file.

---

**Solution 2**

If you still wanna use `minifyEnabled` you will also have to follow these steps.

I. Add `extra-gen-snapshot-options=--obfuscate` to your `android/gradle.properties`

II. Create `/android/app/proguard-rules.pro` file and add rules listed below.

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
```

III. In your `build.gradle(app)`, add this

```
buildTypes {

    release {

        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```