# Flutter initialization failed, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found

Tags: android, flutter

The app runs properly on iOS, but when I try to run it on an android I get the following error

```
E/FlutterLoader( 9150): Flutter initialization failed.
E/FlutterLoader( 9150): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:178)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:289)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine.<init>(FlutterEngine.java:192)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:234)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:154)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:410)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libflutter.so" not found
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:129)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader$1.call(FlutterLoader.java:123)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/FlutterLoader( 9150):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I tried all the fixes suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795414/flutter-app-drops-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-libflutter-so), but none of them resolved the problem

Comment: +1 My situation gets even weird. The app runs with emulator and real device but produces this exception in release.

Comment: Best thing you can do: Get rid off flutter :-D. If that's not possible, be aware that Flutter is a cache hell and you have to become a cache master...
This error can be fixed due clearing caches on app-cache on device/emulator or deinstall previous app on device/emulator

Answer (score 4):

I uninstall and `Clean Project` (By Android Studio). And run again it's work for me.

Answer (score 2):

uninstalling the app on the emulator and restarting the emulator fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because in the past I tried to minimize build times and removed the x86_64 build. Removing that will break the emulator for x86 cpu's.

In android\app\build.gradle

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ndk {
                // The line below only builds arm64-v8a 
                abiFilters  'arm64-v8a' // This breaks running the app in the emulator
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64' // this includes all build targets 
                

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .gradle in the flutter folder. After that run the app it will take some to download new gradle when the will download, app will run succesfully.

Answer (score -1):

Use some other emulators or real device, it will work properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).