# Error on Google Play Console -- java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I created a release on Google Play Console, and when Google checks my code it finds this error. However when I compile the application myself, there is no error.
I code in Flutter, so all android files are automatically generated by flutter
Would you have an idea?
Thanks in advance

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz, PID: 7595
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz/com.example.app_yoorgreat.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
    at o0.d.e(Unknown Source:441)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:184)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(Unknown Source:12)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.G(Unknown Source:106)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.p(Unknown Source:7)
    at io.flutter.embedding.android.d.onCreate(Unknown Source:13)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:2)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
    at o0.d.e(Unknown Source:28)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-wn4M9L26y34CKgj1FdF3Ag==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.yoorgreat.yoorquizz-IjonJonnrboy1C5YqCK7nQ==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1012)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(Unknown Source:13)
    at o0.d$a.b(Unknown Source:18)
    at o0.d$a.call(Unknown Source:0)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app drops java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError (couldn't find "libflutter.so")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795414/flutter-app-drops-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-libflutter-so)

Comment: same problem did you find a solution?