# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ... ... couldn't find "libflutter.so"

Tags: flutter

I found a lot of this issue in production and still could not solved.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.thitsarparami.app/com.ryanheise.audioservice.AudioServiceActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.thitsarparami.app-a-dcbjkGZG7bhB8y1Z4zZw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.thitsarparami.app-a-dcbjkGZG7bhB8y1Z4zZw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3897)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4076)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

### Device specifications
Model name
Pixel 2 (virtual)
Manufacturer
Google
Android version
Android 9 (SDK 28)
Locale
th_TH
Screen size
1080 x 1920
Screen density (DPI)
441
RAM (total memory)

### OpenGL ES version

ABI
armeabi
CPU

flutter doctor

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
• Flutter version 3.0.5 at /Users/aungmyooo/Development/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision f1875d570e (5 days ago), 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
• Engine revision e85ea0e79c
• Dart version 2.17.6
• DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/aungmyooo/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7590822)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.1)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.44.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
• iPhone (mobile) • 06e02964e429eeebf29550b03ef955abe09891ef • ios            • iOS 15.5 19F77
• macOS (desktop) • macos                                    • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 103.0.5060.114

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
• All required HTTP hosts are available

Answer (score 2):

This is the salient part of the error message:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ... 
... couldn't find "libflutter.so"
```

This appears to be a build-time issue.

It's been reported multiple different times over multiple different versions.  I see several "workarounds" ... but no "fix".

Specifically:

> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32756
>
> Seems like uninstalling the app and reinstalling fixed it, error
> occured without changing anything in the code, just opened up Android
> studio again and pressed the run button...

See also:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65032771/421195
>
> Flutter does not currently support building for x86 Android (See
> [Issue 9253](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253)).
>
> Add following code under the buildTypes in android\app\build.gradle
>
> ```
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         ndk {
>             abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86_64'
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

... and ...

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/69998842/421195
>
> In app level build.gradle following line should be added
>
> ```
> defaultConfig {
>     ...
>     ndk { abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a","x86_64", "mips", 
>      "mips64", "arm64-v8a" }
> }
> ```

SUGGESTION: Review the threads, post back and let us know if any of the suggestions worked for you.

Comment: thank for suggestion. I will test and let you know.

Comment: No suggestions worked for me. I have added as follow
defaultConfig {
    ...
    ndk { abiFilters "armeabi", "x86", "armeabi-v7a","x86_64", "mips", 
     "mips64", "arm64-v8a" }
}

Comment: Q: Are you able to reproduce this yourself ... or does it only happen with users who've downloaded and installed your app?  Q: Which specific models?  Pixel 2 only, or other Android models, too?  If you're able to reproduce in your lab, does the SAME build fail on ALL models?  Or just certain models?

Comment: Happening the same with me as well. Crashlytics says all devices which this is happening are rooted devices