# How to resolve Flutter unsatisfied link error?

Tags: flutter

In Firebase crashlytics, I am getting the following information about the crash.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myawesomeapp/com.example.myawesomeapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-dghasjbcdcjdfhcn==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-dghasjbcdcjdfhcn==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-dghasjbcdcjdfhcn==/split_config.es.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-dghasjbcdcjdfhcn==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-zqi6k7PQCL8VlHwCIoANUA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-dghasjbcdcjdfhcn==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-dghasjbcdcjdfhcn==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-dghasjbcdcjdfhcn==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-dghasjbcdcjdfhcn==/split_config.es.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-dghasjbcdcjdfhcn==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.myawesomeapp-zqi6k7PQCL8VlHwCIoANUA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter app drops java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError (couldn't find "libflutter.so")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795414/flutter-app-drops-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-libflutter-so)

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak No, I have already gone through that solution, that seems to be related with APK and I have to build appbundle.