# {Flutter Error} My signed APK is crashing on lots of devices (In App open) but the debug version is working fine (Err - couldn't find "libflutter.so")

Tags: android, flutter, apk, release

Full Error -

```
Flutter initialization failed.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"


at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
.
.
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
.
.
2023-10-24 02:08:48.846 19827-19827 AndroidRuntime com.example.rain D Shutting down VM
2023-10-24 02:08:48.851 19827-19827 AndroidRuntime com.example.rain E FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rain, PID: 19827
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rain/com.example.rain.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
at c2.f.g(Unknown Source:478)
.
.
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.rain--############==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.rain--############==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary(Unknown Source:13)
at c2.f$a.b(Unknown Source:18)
at c2.f$a.call(Unknown Source:0)
```

**Important Points:**

- I have been stuck with this issue for more than 4 days and tried lots of solutions but nothing has been helpful.

These are some links where these errors are discussed -

1. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83596
2. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32756
3. [Flutter app drops java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError (couldn't find "libflutter.so")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795414/flutter-app-drops-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-couldnt-find-libflutter-so)

There are lots of developers getting this error and getting frustrated because of it.. its not even get solved by Flutter GitHub account as you can see the links I provided people opened it and its getting closed somehow.. **PLEASE HELP!!!**

**Thanks In advance**

Comment: This could be caused by users trying to side-load your app but only installing the `base.apk` that does not contain the native libraries. The path `lib/x86` indicates that this happens on en emulator. So an alternative explanation is that the builds you provide are only for real devices (arm-v7/arm-v8a) therefore the app crashes as it misses the required libraries on an x86 emulator. In the end this seems more like a problem caused by the user that is not of yor conccern.